# Should i need to install or include the framework extrnally?

Tags: php, eclipse

I have installed XAMPP in my windows xp machine. and I am using the Eclipse as an Editor. I haven't include or installed the framework yet. And inside the Program Files/XAMP/php folder I noticed a PEAR directory. Is that enough or should I install/include the framework externally.

Comment: You only need to install the framework (whichever that is) if you actually want to use it. Eclipse and PHP work fine without it usually. -- You should explain a bit more detailed/thoroughly what you are attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be suffering from a bit of confusion.

XAMPP is an "all-in-one" installation of a web server (Apache), PHP, and a database (MySQL) and a few more tools.

Eclipse is an IDE.

*Neither* of these things are frameworks.<sup>*</sup>

[PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) is a package repository, not unlike Perl's [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) or Python's [<s>Cheese Shop</s> Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).  PEAR isn't a framework either.

If you want to use a PHP framework, you are going to need to obtain it and install it yourself.  Note that *most* frameworks do not require separate, system-level installation, and can simply be bundled with your code.  Some frameworks *allow* system-level installation, and even use the PEAR infrastructure to do so.  Refer to each framework's *specific documentation* for more information on how to best install them.

<sup>*<sup>Yes, Eclipse could be kind of a framework maybe, but let's *not* go there.</sup></sup>

Comment: How to add framework... I am looking for xdebug framework. How to add this. What will be the use of this.??

Comment: @Gnanendra, [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/index.php) is *not* a framework.  It is a debugging and profiling tool.  Is that what you are trying to work with?  If so, follow that link for documentation, installation instructions and download links.

Comment: Thanks @Charles, Really I am totally nil in this(PHP). Because i am from ASP.net. Please let me know the use of installing xdbug and other frameworks.

Comment: @Gnanendra, welcome to PHP!  I want to warn you that these all-in-one installers can be a *real* bear to work with -- they install a *lot* of things.  The xdebug page I linked to you above contains complete and thorough documentation on how to use the debugging and profiling features.  If you run into trouble, you'll want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just experimenting, using the XAMPP PEAR version is fine. If PEAR isn't installed, go-pear.bat will install it for you from the php directory. However, if you want to deploy the app made with the framework, you really should create a local copy of the PEAR install directory (using `pear install -R <dir> package` option), because you don't want to upgrade PEAR and break your deployed app.

Comment: Depends on the framework. PEAR is not really a framework, as noted by @charles. It's a package management system. Symfony, for example, can be installed via PEAR. You'll have to refer to the specific framework's docs. If you just mean PEAR packages, install PEAR first by running go-pear.bat in the php folder if it's not already installed, then do pear install <packagename>.

Comment: I am looking for xdebug, for that should i install PEAR first??